# Azure Fabrics Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, service-fabric-stateless

I have stateless Web API services on Azure Fabrics + independent UI on React.

- UI calls services
- Services call each other over http

I would like to authenticate user by email or/and social networks (facebook)

What are my options? Examples? Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWT is an answer, there is an explanation http://alexander.holbreich.org/jwt/